# Global coordinates of child node

Tags: snap.svg

This question is quite simple, but I can't solve it by myself.
How to get global coordinates of child element?
In my case I have a group and few nested groups within that. Then I need to get coordinates of some inner elements of something which I've already moved and rotated.
I tried to get local position of interested object, and then to apply global transformation, but the result was not same as I expected.

**EDIT**
[Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/4ucDL/) a little demo of what I have and what I need.
We have few nested groups, on which we apply some transformations. Then I need say coordinates of `CIRCLE#target`'s center relative to SVG. As you can see it would be something like 77x131.

Comment: Can you put up a jsfiddle of your example, so we can take a look ?

Comment: Please explain me how can I attach Sanp.Svg source (v0.2.0) to fiddle?

Comment: Hi, go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and put the respective code in there. You can include external resources on the left hand side, or include as a script source pulled in via js.

Comment: Oh, sorry for ambiguous question. I use Snap.Svg 0.2.0, but I found only 0.1.0 CDN hosted version, I tried to attach url to raw on GitHub, but it's don't work. :(

Comment: @Ian, sorry for my stupidity, in case of demo there is no matter what version of Snap to use. I've updated my Question, here is quick link to fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4ucDL/)

Comment: Its worth noting how it differs between browsers, offsetX doesn't seem reliable. Is it possible to base it from e.clientX or e.pageX ?

Comment: The core of my problem is not capturing mouse coordinates relative to SVG, that was made for illustrative purposes. I think I've already spotted a hole to jump in, should test it tommorow.

Comment: Reading [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) sometimes is very interesting and useful, and there is a possibility to transform user space (local to target element) coordinates to outermost SVG element coordinate system, using transformation matrices, but we still should traverse all parents of target element, to get correct result. However, I didn't realized is there another more cheap way to do that yet.